# Calculate matrix column mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I've got this matrix:

```
      [[[ 0.49757494  0.50242506]
      [ 0.50340754  0.49659246]
      [ 0.50785456  0.49214544]
         ..., 
      [ 0.50817149  0.49182851]
      [ 0.50658656  0.49341344]
      [ 0.49419885  0.50580115]]

      [[ 0.117       0.883     ]
      [ 0.604       0.396     ]
      [ 1.          0.        ]
         ..., 
      [ 0.98559675  0.01440325]
      [ 0.948       0.052     ]
      [ 0.012       0.988     ]]

      [[ 0.21099179  0.78900821]
      [ 0.75212493  0.24787507]
      [ 0.96653919  0.03346081]
           ..., 
      [ 0.97485074  0.02514926]
      [ 0.95051503  0.04948497]
      [ 0.05409603  0.94590397]]]
```

If the weights are w1,w2,w3, how can I calculate the mean of first column and second column for each matrix (3 by 2) ? So I can get like:

```
      [[[(X1        Y1]
        ...,
      [X2           Y2]
      [[X3          Y3]
        ...,
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: input shape is  (3, 37375, 2), and I would like to have instead of a (3,2), a (1,2). I would like to get the mean for each column, example:

```
   (0.497*w1 + 0.503*w2 + 0.507*w3)/ (w1 + w2 + w3)     <--- First column
```

Comment: What `.shape` is the input, and what `.shape` do you want the output to be?

Comment: I did edit please check it

Comment: Do you want `(1,1)` or `(1,2)`?  If `(1,1)` how do you condense the second axis?  Also your weighting factors seem to be working on the long axis instead of the `3` axis in your example.  You sure you don't mean `(0.497*w1 + 0.117*w2 + 0.211*w3)/ (w1 + w2 + w3)`?

Comment: oh sry yea (1,2)

Comment: I'm not sure the shape of your input allows you what you would like to do. The numbers of your "First column" in your edit belong to the axis with length 37375. Compare the output of ```np.arange(3*5*2).reshape((3,5,2))``` which creates an array of shape ```(3,5,2)``` (take the 5 as your 37375). It's not clear to me what information each axis should hold.

Comment: Still no sure what you mean then.  What is the size of the weighting vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input shape is `(3,n,2)` and you want the shape to be `(n,3,2)` you will want first to do

```
in=in.reshape((-1,3,2))
```

If you have a weighting vector `w`

```
w = np.random.rand(3)
```

Then you can do weighted average over the first axis with `np.average` (yielding `(n,2)`

```
out1 = np.average(in, weights = w, axis = 1)
```

Or you can do a weighted sum

```
out1 = np.sum(t*w[None,:, None], axis = 1) / np.sum(w)
```

Comment: Instead of using ```np.mean``` you can use ```np.average``` which allows to specify a ```weights``` parameter ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html))

Comment: your answer seems to work but I think it calculates the average of all the n obseravtions, I would like to have instead n matrices of (1,2)

Comment: so you want an output shape of `(n,2)`?

Comment: [ 0.49757494  0.50242506]
             [ 0.50340754  0.49659246]
             [ 0.50785456  0.49214544] this is first matrix

Comment: I've took it from the sample, above, so If I understood you well, yea its (n,2)

Comment: OK, so you need to reshape your initial data.  That was what was confusing, as I thought you wanted to cast `w.size=3` against your initial `in.shape[0]=3` axis

Comment: It worked nice one thanks ! One more thing, how can I take the first column and stack it inside a dataframe ?

Comment: Probably want to ask another question.  I'm not a `pandas` expert